# Swift Socket readline writeline

Tags: swift, sockets, readline

Sorry my first question is error; I want to ask for Swift Socket not Java

I am trying to write a Swift client app and connect to Java Server.

I don't know how to use Socket in Swift client.

I want to have like below Java function(out.println and in.readline)

THanks

The Java code was taken mostly from an Oracle example.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;

out.println("Hello World");

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(inputLine);
System.out.flush();

out.println("test");

if (inputLine.equals("Bye")) {
    break;
   }
}

out.close();
in.close();
socket.close();
```

Sorry for typing error question first time

Can u teach me where can I find how to implement by Swift in official website? or teach me how to implement ?
thx much ><

my swift code is below, and  I don't know how to get String form readline (inputStream).

And I write

```
outputstream.write(queryString,maxLength: queryString.characters.count)
```

and try to send to server.

But server always receives lost some content in sendString.

My server is ok in Android with Socket

```
let addr = "xxooo"
    let port = 10009

    var inp : NSInputStream?
    var out : NSOutputStream?

    NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(addr, port: port, inputStream: &inp, outputStream: &out)
    print("test1")
    let inputstream = inp!
    let outputstream = out!
    inputstream.open()
    outputstream.open()
    print("test2 queryString=\(queryString)")

      outputstream.write(queryString,maxLength:queryString.characters.count)
    print("test3 \(queryString.characters.count)")
    let buffersize = 1024
    var buffer = Array<UInt8>(count : buffersize,repeatedValue :0)

    let bytesRead = inputstream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffersize)
    var getString : NSString?
    print("test4")

    if(bytesRead>0){
        getString = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: bytesRead, encoding:  NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("getString = \(getString!)")

    }else{

    }
    inputstream.close()
    outputstream.close()
```

Comment: TCP sockets absolutely don't care about the programming language on either end.

Comment: I know but I don't know Swift language how to implement.
Can u teach me where can I find in official website?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html

Comment: thx @ravindra , I read before , but I don't know how to implement now...
Can u teach me example code  > <  
By the way I want readline and out.printline
PS: 
I want have simple code like in official website.
Like below
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm

Answer (score 1):

You have to **flush()** PrintWriter to receive data on other end of Socket. You are calling System.out.flush() and not PrintWriter out.**flush()**

```
out.flush() // This will do the trick for you.
```

Have a look this article regarding [socket programming](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/)

**EDIT:**

In any programming language, the socket communication mechanism remains same except change in function names.

**Server:**

1) Create a ServerSocket

2) Accept a Client Socket in a infinite loop

3) Open OutputStream on Client Socket and write data.

4) Open InputStream to read the data

**Client**

1) Open a Socket to Server on a particular IP & port

2) Open OutputStream on the Socket

3) Write Data to the Stream (on wrapper of the Stream with Writers)

4) Open Input Stream to read the data

Have a look at this [**Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863550/using-sockets-in-swift-like-in-java) for swift client implementation of socket.

Have a look at Swift client and Java server [**article**](http://www.frattv.com/connect-with-a-swift-client-to-a-java-server-using-sockets/) and [**SE question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28655425/how-to-test-if-my-remote-socket-nsstream-are-correctly-open)

Comment: Excuse me , maybe me English is not strong.
I want to ask answer is Swift not Java.
thx for your reply><

Comment: QQ I found that my question is error, where can  I edit ,I try to find now

Comment: I had tried, but I don't know how to get String form readline (inputStream). And I write outputstream.write(sendString,maxLength: sendString.characters.count) and try to send to server. But server always receives lost some content in sendString My server is ok in Android with Socket .
thank u @ravindra

Comment: Can you add your swift client code in the question?

Comment: Have a look at : stackoverflow.com/questions/28655425/how-to-test-if-my-remote-socket-nsstream-are-correctly-open

Comment: thank u
I have tried,but not answer my question.
that question is how to test are correctly open.  this is not my question. 

my server have received data, but lost some content in sendString. 

I want to have like Java function(out.println and in.readline) in my question

Comment: But you already have outputstream.write and inputstream.read which are equivalent to out.println and in.readLine

Comment: thank u help me, because u said outputstream.write and inputstream.read which are equivalent to out.println and in.readLine. 

I try to send English and success, but I change to Chinese it error...
for example I want to send "哈囉我是中文國喔快收下我吧"
But Server just receive 哈囉我是中.........

Comment: Good to heat that it is working for english. You have to set character encoding. Look out for that api in swift.

Comment: I success reference by this and ravindra 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25554986/how-to-convert-string-to-unsafepointeruint8-and-length

thank u again 3Q

Comment: By the way, outputstream.write and inputstream.read which are "not" equivalent to out.println and in.readLine.
Because println and readline use String in java, but outputstream.write and inputstream.read use byte.